# How to add filter and limits on embeded models in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a data schema in MongoDB with two different models `Clinic` and `Doctor`.

`Clinic` has doctors ids embedded who are working in the same clinic.

`Clinic`

```
{
    clinicName: "XYZ Hopital",
    clinicAddress: "ABC place.",
    "doctorsWorking":{
        "doctorId1":{
            "doctorJoined": ISODate("2017-03-15T10:47:47.647Z")
        },
        "doctorId2":{
            "doctorJoined": ISODate("2017-04-15T10:47:47.647Z")
        },
        "doctorId3":{
            "doctorJoined": ISODate("2017-05-15T10:47:47.647Z")
        },
        ...
        ...
        //upto 3000-4000 more records suppose
    }
}
```

`Doctor`

```
{
    id: "doctorId1",
    doctorName: "XYZ Hopital",
    doctorAddress: "ABC place.",
}
```

**Questions**

1. How to query for those `doctor's Ids` from `Clinic` model who has joined the clinic before date `"2017-05-15"`?
2. How to query for clinic `XYZ Hospital` with only first 40 doctor in items.
3. Does this embedded model structure will have some kinds of performance effect as doctors items go on increasing in future.

I don't want to use an array here for storing `doctors Ids` list in the Clinic model as performance will get hit if we the number of doctors keeps on increasing Also I will need to query doctors by id present in a clinic which can be efficiently done using object schema.

Comment: If you don't want to use an array for embedding the doctor's info instead of using hash keys then it's going to be extremely difficult to query for the dates within those hash keys as you would need to know the id's beforehand to query. That being said, the above schema is only good for writes but poor for reads as explained before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following schema for the `clinic` collection will suite you better here:

```
{
    'clinicName': 'XYZ',
    'clinicAddress': 'ABC',
    'doctorsWorking': [
        {
            'docID': 123
            'docName': 'doc A',
            'joined': ISODate("2017-03-15T10:47:47.647Z")
        },
        {
            'docID': 456
            'docName': 'doc B',
            'joined': ISODate("2017-05-15T10:47:47.647Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

To query for the docID's who joined the clinic before a certain date you can use the aggregation framework:

```
db.clinic.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$doctorsWorking'},
    {'$match': {'doctorsWorking': {'$gte': ISODate('...')}}},
    {'$project': {'doctorsWorking.docID': 1, '_id': 0}}
])
# {'doctorsWorking': {'docID': 456}}  # this will return doctors as documents
```

To limit this to 40 docs use the `sort` and `limit` stages:

```
db.clinic.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$doctorsWorking'},
    {'$match': {'doctorsWorking': {'$gte': ISODate('...')}}},
    {'$sort': {'doctorsWorking.joined': 1}},
    {'$limit': 40},
    {'$project': {'doctorsWorking.docID': 1, '_id': 0}}
])
# returns same as above
```

You can use the `distinct` method to query for all doctor ID's given a clinic:

```
db.clinic.distinct(field='doctorsWorking.docID', query={'clinicName': 'XYZ'})
# [123, 456]
```

Or query for all doctor ID's in the entire collection:

```
db.clinic.distinct(field='doctorsWorking.docID')
# [123, 456, etc.]
```

You really don't need a separate `doctors` collection - unless you have a ton of data for each doctor in which case it may be easier to just store the docID in `clinic` and map it to the separate `doctors` collection.